# 'Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action' on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise and trying to redirect my user after sign up form to a specific template.

I've checked the docs about `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method but I am receiving an exception saying I am redirecting twice.

```
RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def create
    super
    UsersCreateJob.perform_later(resource.id) if resource.persisted?
end

protected

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   render template: 'devise/registrations/success'
end
```

```
Exception

AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in RegistrationsController#create

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

As far as I understand, the `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method overwrites the one from Devise Registration Controller and redirect to my template, right? Where this other template is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

`after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` is not meant to render a view. It's a path that will be used for redirect. You should just put a path to an action rendering`'devise/registrations/success'`.

The error you see is cause by the fact that the devise controller calls render/redirect and then you try to call it as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mrzasa but it is a little bit confusing for me. I am creating a method called success, also the route for it and making after_inactive_sign_up_path_for redirect to "success_path", which has 'devise/registrations/success', but getting the same error. Did I understand everything wrong? :(

Comment: you shouldn't redirect in `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`, just return a path to the method:`def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for; success_path; end`

Comment: If I do this, my resource comes nil, which means it is not passing through my create method. After my create, I want to redirect to a specific view saying his/her sign up was successful (yet he/she needs to confirm email).